# search bar in javascript to search similar names even if spelt wrong

Tags: javascript, search

I have my search bar all setup using a javascript style database with around 200 pages to search but I want the javascript to return a name even if is spelt slightly wrong e.g the user types Cory haim they will get Corey haim

also along with this I was wondering if you can open a search result in the current window instead of opening a new window I have tried the usual methods such as self; and that...

see my code below....

```
function openPage() {
        var x = document.getElementById("search").value;
             x = x.replace(/\b\w/g, (firstLetter) => firstLetter.toUpperCase());

//=======================================================================================

            if (x === "Aaron Carter") { 
                 window.open ("files/aaroncarter.html"); 
              }
            if (x === "Albert Einstein") {
                window.open ("files/alberteinstein.html");
            }
}
```

```
<input type="search" id="search" autocomplete="off" onchange="openPage()"  class="form-control rounded-pill rounded-end-0 border-0 ps-4" placeholder="Search Celebrity Bones... e.g. Stan Laurel">
                  <button type="button" id="button" onclick="openPage()" value="Chercher" class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill rounded-start-0 shadow-none">
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                  </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

That sounds  a bit complex, you want your code to be able to decipher a mispelling and produce the right result. Your example makes it more complex than what a normal javascript function will be able to do:

If you wanted min to produce mind or mine, that's easy, but if you want cory to produce corey that's hard. I recommend using a library that has been built to help in this instance.

Try:

https://fusejs.io/

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called fuzzy logic. The typical solutions to this is to calculate how many changes is needed to get from the search query to any possible result and then picking the most likely result.

There is an algorithm called [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) that calculates this difference, which is the most common way of doing fuzzy comparison on strings.

There is a lot of good tutorials on the web and i recommend [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/levenshtein-distance-in-javascript)s Levenshtein Distance in JavaScript.

Based on that tutorial code, a solution should probably look something like this:

```js
/**
 * SortBySimilarity
 *  
 * Sorts "possibleSearchResults" by  how closely they match "query" *
 * @param {string} query
 * @param {string[]} possibleSearchResults
 * @return {string[]} 
 */
function SortBySimilarity(query, possibleSearchResults) {
    // Sorts "possibleSearchResults" by  how closely they match "query"
    return possibleSearchResults
        .slice(0)
        .sort((a, b) => {
            return LevenshteinDistance(a, query) - LevenshteinDistance(b, query);
        })
}
/**
 * LevenshteinDistance
 * 
 * Calculates how similar two strings are, using the Levenshtein-distance algorithm
 * Code taken from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/levenshtein-distance-in-javascript
 * @param {string} str1
 * @param {string} str2
 * @return {number} 
 */
function LevenshteinDistance(str1, str2) {
    const track = Array(str2.length + 1).fill(null).map(() => Array(str1.length + 1).fill(null));
    for (let i = 0; i <= str1.length; i += 1) {
        track[0][i] = i;
    }
    for (let j = 0; j <= str2.length; j += 1) {
        track[j][0] = j;
    }
    for (let j = 1; j <= str2.length; j += 1) {
        for (let i = 1; i <= str1.length; i += 1) {
            const indicator = str1[i - 1] === str2[j - 1] ? 0 : 1;
            track[j][i] = Math.min(
                track[j][i - 1] + 1, // deletion
                track[j - 1][i] + 1, // insertion
                track[j - 1][i - 1] + indicator, // substitution
            );
        }
    }
    return track[str2.length][str1.length];
}

// Implementation


let possibleSearchResults = [
    "Aaron Carter",
    "Albert Einstein",
    'Corey haim',
];

let query = 'Cory haim';

function ParseQuery(query) {
    let results = SortBySimilarity(query, possibleSearchResults);

    console.clear()
    console.log({
        query,
        mostLikely: results[0],
        possibleSearchResults,
        results,
    });

    return results[0];
}

let searchField = document.getElementById("search-field")
searchField.addEventListener('input', evt => {
    let result = ParseQuery(searchField.value)
    // Do something with the result
})
```

```html
<input id="search-field" />
```

However this code is still not entirely enough for full fuzzy logic. Searching for "albert" for instance will give you "Aaron Carter" as the most likely result, since it takes less edits to change it to "Aaron Carter" than to add the letters for "Albert Einstein". This can be handled by changing the "costs" in the levenshtein-distance calculation, for instance by making insertions cheaper than the other methods.

Also the above implementation is case-sensitive.

Comment: hey dude thanks but ice no idea on this so ill just use what I've got, thanks anyways